# Run a SBT task with arguments from command line

Tags: scala, command-line, sbt, task, scalatest

I want to hava a SBT task which takes comma-separated list of test classes given by their fully qualified name as input from command line. Now that I run the task with hard-coded value but I want to get it from command line. Can someone help me in writing a task like this.

```
 lazy val runTask = inputKey[Unit]("custom run")

 runTask := {
    val one = (runMain in Compile).fullInput(" org.scalatest.tools.Runner -P1 -C reporter.TestReporter -o -s testcase.GetAccountInfo -s testcase.GetProfileInfo").evaluated
 }
```

Something like this,

```
 sbt runTask testcase.GetProfileInfo,testcase.GetAccountInfo
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16):

You have to have a [Parser](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Parsing-Input.html), which will parse the input given to the task. Once you have the input, you can convert [`(runMain in Compile).toTask`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Extending/Input-Tasks.html#get-a-task-from-an-inputtask), and feed the input to the task.

#### TL;DR; `build.sbt`

```
import sbt.complete._

import complete.DefaultParsers._

lazy val myRunTask = inputKey[Unit]("Runs actual tests")

lazy val FullQualifiedClassName = 
  (charClass(c => isScalaIDChar(c) || (c == '.'), "class name")).+.string

def commaDelimited(display: String) =
  token(Space) ~> repsep(token(FullQualifiedClassName, display), token(","))

lazy val testClassArgs: Parser[Seq[String]] = 
  commaDelimited("<full qualified test class name>").map { 
    xs: Seq[String] => xs.map(e => s" -s $e ")
  }

myRunTask := Def.inputTaskDyn {
  val classes = testClassArgs.parsed
  runMainInCompile(classes)
}.evaluated

def runMainInCompile(classes: Seq[String]) = Def.taskDyn {
  (runMain in Compile).toTask(s" org.scalatest.tools.Runner -P1 -C reporter.TestReporter -o ${classes.mkString}")
}
```

### Parser

Let's start with a parser. The parser must take a space, followed by your classes separated by comma.

Let's first defined a parser, which parses full qualified class name:

```
lazy val FullQualifiedClassName = 
      (charClass(c => isScalaIDChar(c) || (c == '.'), "class name")).+.string
```

Once we have the parser, we can combine it together with another parser. We need to create a parser, which takes comma separated full qualified class names:

```
def commaDelimited(display: String) = 
      token(Space) ~> repsep(token(FullQualifiedClassName, display), token(","))
```

The `~>` operator means that the input on the left of it will be discarded. The value returned from the parser is a `Seq[String]` of the full qualified class names.

Judging from your question, you want your classes to be prefixed with `-s`. You could do it later, but just to show one more feature of parsers, I'll just do it here.

You can take an output of a parser and convert it to another output, using `map`.

```
lazy val testClassArgs: Parser[Seq[String]] = 
  commaDelimited("<full qualified test class name>").map { 
    xs: Seq[String] => xs.map(e => s" -s $e ")
  }
```

OK, we're almost there.

### Run InputTask with arguments combined with a static string

We can define a new input task key. I'll chose `myRunTask`, because otherwise it will collide with `runTask`, which already exists.

Let's define a method which takes a sequence of classes (already prefixed with `-s`) as an argument, and which returns a `Task` [obtained](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Extending/Input-Tasks.html#get-a-task-from-an-inputtask) from an `InputTask`.

```
def runMainInCompile(classes: Seq[String]) = Def.taskDyn {
  (runMain in Compile).toTask(s" org.scalatest.tools.Runner -P1 -C reporter.TestReporter -o ${classes.mkString}")
}
```

Now let's combine all elements in one task:

```
myRunTask := Def.inputTaskDyn {
  val classes = testClassArgs.parsed
  runMainInCompile(classes)
}.evaluated
```

Comment: Hi Ipiepiora, 
Thanks for answering. I'm getting the following import errors.
  \build.sbt:52: error: not found: value charClass
  (charClass(c => isScalaIDChar(c) || (c == '.'), "class name")).+.string
   ^
D:\Workspaces\KeplerWS_2\cross-browser-test\build.sbt:57: error: not found: type Parser
lazy val testClassArgs: Parser[Seq[String]] =
\build.sbt:55: error: not found: value token
  token(Space) ~> repsep(token(FullQualifiedClassName, display), token(","))
sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression

Comment: Am I missing something ? I'm new to SBT. Kindly guide me.

Comment: @Sarath are you running it on sbt 0.13.5 ? Have you tried with just creating a `build.sbt` file, with only my content from the first code snippet

Comment: Hi lpiepiora, I'm using sbt 0.13. I created a build.sbt file with the content you posted. Getting some imports problem.

Comment: Can you try with sbt 0.13.5 ? Also remember that new lines are important, do not concatenate lines, which are not concatenated in my snippet.

Comment: Now that i included all the imports with the methods. For eg., complete.DefaultParsers.isScalaIDChar, complete.DefaultParsers.repsep, complete.Parser.token, complete.Parser.
And I changed that .+.string to toString
No errors now. 
How am I supposed to run with the args.

Comment: You should be able to run it just like you've stated in your OP. However changing `.+.string` to `toString` is not a good idea. I am certain that my code should work in new project on sbt 0.13.5, just as I've typed it in above.

Comment: @Sarath you can check working example in my github repository https://github.com/lpiepiora/stack-overflow/tree/master/solutions/q-23952566

Comment: The `FullQualifiedClassName` is pretty dense. How did you figure that out?  Did you use a built-in from sbt `complete` as a startign point?